# Get Data from Gridview to other Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, key, enter

I have Windows form `form1` where pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> key opens a new `form2`. In that `form2` there is a datagridview showing different values. Now, on pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> key in `form2` I get selected value of datagridview. Issue is I want to move that value to previous `form1` but when I try it opens a new form and moves the value.

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        Form37 f = new Form37();
        f.a = 1;
        f.v = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString();

        f.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: are you using MDI Forms????

Comment: you should use static variables to move from 1 form to another form

Comment: Don't call DataGridViews just GridViews as these two are quite different Controls and make your question look like it belong to WPF!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second form needs a reference to the first one:

**Form37:**

Edit the `Form37` keydown event

```
private void Form37_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        Form38 f = new Form38();
        f.caller_form = this;
        this.Hide();
        f.Show();
    }
}
```

**Form38:**

Add a new variable to your `Form38` class's root:

```
public partial class Form38 : Form
    {
       Form37 caller_form;
```

Edit the `Form38`'s `dataGridView1`'s keydown event

```
private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        Form37 f = caller_form;
        f.a = 1;
        f.v = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString();
        f.Show();
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you replace the line:
**Form37 f = new Form37();**
With the new form1_link:
**Form37 f = form1_link;**
?

Comment: Lets clear things. I have to initiate form38 from form37 on "ENTER" key press. when form38 shows up, I have to go back to form37 with some data on "ENTER" key press. Now please edit your answer according to requirements.

Comment: Thanks it is working. I have one more question. I have datagridview on form37 also and I want variable "v" to display in a particular cell of datagridview after pressing Enter key on form38.

Comment: You need to edit the `datagridview`'s `Modifiers` property to `Public` on `Form37`.

Then after this line:
`f.v = dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString();`
Add a new line:
`f.datagridview.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = f.v;`

Edit the row number and cell number to desired values

Answer (score 0):

```
        //  Mimize Your From1 using
          From1.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
         //..... 

        // Key press On data Grid
        //.....


        //using this get from37 and 
    foreach (Form  frms in this.MdiChildren)
{
    if (frms is from37 )
    {
        if (frms.WindowState==FormWindowState.Minimized)
        {
            frms.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

            //Minimized current form;
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what if I do not want to use MDI forms? then what may be the solution?

Comment: ypu have to persist the instance of form somewhere. If you set Visible false it will destroy object and next time it will create new one.